# How to make Tomcat 6.0 log the console?

Tags: tomcat, logging, console

How can I configure Tomcat 6.0 (running under Centos 5.3) to log what comes out of my web app's console (System.out/err)? Is it possible to specify a path and file size limit as well?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages get sent to catalina.out by default, though you can modify this behavior:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q6

Comment: Thank you Jim! I can't believe I didn't notice it before.

Comment: No problem. I didn't notice it in the FAQ, either. I already knew the answer to your question and searched the web for the answer so I could give you a link!